# YAML configuration file: Why 'example' instead of :example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I set up an environment YAML file for environment specific variables like username and password. To use these variables in my app, I need to use `APP_CONFIG['username']` instead of `APP_CONFIG[:username]`. Why is this? How would I enable the latter instead? Not a major issue, but it bothers me to not know the cause of the difference.

**config/initializers/load_app_config.rb**

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml")[Rails.env]
```

**config/app_config.yml**

```
development:
  username: development_name
  password: secret

production:
  username: production_name
  password: super_secret
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, a YAML key is rendered as String.

```
development:
  username: development_name
  password: secret
```

is accessible by

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml")[Rails.env]
APP_CONFIG['development']['username']
# => "development_name"
```

I you want a specific key to be a symbol, you should prefix it with : in the YAML file.

```
development:
  :username: development_name
  :password: secret

APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml")[Rails.env]
APP_CONFIG['development'][:username]
# => "development_name"
APP_CONFIG['development']['username']
# => nil
```

Normally, this is not done because this is a specific Ruby behavior. Other languages might not be happy about the leading :.

If you specifically wants to access keys as symbol, you can either use `symbolize_keys!`

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml")[Rails.env].simbolize_keys!
```

but most of the time, the effort is not worth. Internally, the 90% of libraries converts Symbols to Strings during a comparison, especially when you deal with hashes with indifferent access. So, at the end of the story, you might want to keep strings in this case.

Last option would be to create a [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html)

```
APP_CONFIG = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml")[Rails.env])
```

This will allow you to access

```
APP_CONFIG[:development][:username]
APP_CONFIG['development'][:username]
APP_CONFIG['development']['username']
```

indifferently. It works by storing the hash keys to string internally and converting the request to `[]` to string, so that it always works. This is the class used by several Rails components, including the famous `params[]` hash in the controllers.

Comment: Thanks very much @Simone, for the very detailed answer. It's very helpful to know the rationale behind the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use `symbolize_keys` on the hash returned by YAML.load_file

Comment: Perfect, thanks @rmk. Is there any important reason to choose one way over another? Or is it just personal preference (ie. "keys look cooler")

Comment: Well, symbols are faster to access than strings, but I do not believe it makes a big difference. It's just that it's more rubyish to use symbols rather than keys.

Comment: Thanks @rmk. That was what I was thinking as well. Simone had an interesting point though: "Internally, the 90% of libraries converts Symbols to Strings during a comparison, especially when you deal with hashes with indifferent access. So, at the end of the story, you might want to keep strings in this case."